# TSQL - Parse address function, unable to return result

Tags: t-sql, substring, sql-function, charindex

Function px_explode will be provided with two parameters:

- separator
- string

Final result will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.px_explode('xxy', 'alfaxxybetaxxygama')
```

and will return

[image]

But...
Query won't finish execution, so I assume that I ran into an infinite loop here, now assuming this, my question might be.

> How can I avoid the infinite loop I ran into and what am I missing?

---

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.px_explode 

    (@separator VARCHAR(10), @string VARCHAR(2000))

 RETURNS @expl_tbl TABLE 

    (val VARCHAR(100))

AS

BEGIN

IF (CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) = 0) and (LTRIM(RTRIM(@string)) <> '')

    INSERT INTO @expl_tbl VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(@string)))

ELSE

BEGIN

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) > 0

    BEGIN

        IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) - 1))) 
   <> '')

            INSERT INTO @expl_tbl VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@string, 
 CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) - 1))))


     END

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@string)) <> ''

        INSERT INTO @expl_tbl VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(@string)))

 END

RETURN 

END
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient split function - you may wish to read the following articles [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up),  [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql), [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: To answer your question though, your while loop is predicated on `CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) > 0`, and through every iteration you never change either of these values, so the loop will never exit - but as above, this is a really inefficient function, so I wouldn't bother fixing it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite is the XML splitter. This needs no function and is fully inlineable. If you can introduce a function to your database, the suggested links in Gareth's comment give you some very good ideas.

This is simple and quite straight forward:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='alfaxxybetaxxygama';
SELECT nd.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'xxy','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') AS B(nd);
```

This will first transform your string to an XML like this

```
<x>alfa</x>
<x>beta</x>
<x>gama</x>
```

... simply by replacing the delimiters `xxy` with XML tags. The rest is easy reading from XML `.nodes()`

Answer (score 1):

Loops are bad and so are mutli-statement table valued functions (e.g. where you define the table). If performance is important then you want a tally table and and inline table valued function (iTVF).

For a high-performing way to resolve this I would first grab a copy of [Ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). The solution you're looking for will look like this:

```
DECLARE @string    varchar(8000) = 'alfaxxybetaxxygama',
        @delimiter varchar(20)  = 'xxy'; -- use 

SELECT
  itemNumber = row_number() over (ORDER BY d.p),
  itemIndex  = isnull(nullif(d.p+l.d, 0),1),
  item       = SUBSTRING
             (
               @string, 
               d.p+l.d, -- delimiter position + delimiter length
               isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter, @string, d.p+l.d),0) - (d.p+l.d), 8000)
             )
FROM (values (len(@string), len(@delimiter))) l(s,d) -- 1 is fine for l.d but keeping uniform
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT -(l.d) union all
  SELECT ng.position
  FROM dbo.NGrams8K(@string, l.d) as ng
  WHERE token = @delimiter
) as d(p); -- delimiter.position
```

Which returns

```
itemNumber           itemIndex            item
-------------------- -------------------- ---------
1                    1                    alfa
2                    8                    beta
3                    15                   gama
```

Against a table it would look like this:

```
DECLARE @table table (string varchar(8000));
INSERT @table VALUES ('abcxxyXYZxxy123'), ('alfaxxybetaxxygama');

DECLARE @delimiter varchar(100) = 'xxy';

SELECT * 
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    itemNumber = row_number() over (ORDER BY d.p),
    itemIndex  = isnull(nullif(d.p+l.d, 0),1),
    item       = SUBSTRING
               (
                 t.string, 
                 d.p+l.d, -- delimiter position + delimiter length
                 isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter, t.string, d.p+l.d),0) - (d.p+l.d), 8000)
               )
  FROM (values (len(t.string), len(@delimiter))) l(s,d) -- 1 is fine for l.d but keeping uniform
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT -(l.d) union all
    SELECT ng.position
    FROM dbo.NGrams8K(t.string, l.d) as ng
    WHERE token = @delimiter
  ) as d(p) -- delimiter.position
) split;
```

Results:

```
string                    itemNumber           itemIndex            item
------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------
abcxxyXYZxxy123           1                    1                    abc
abcxxyXYZxxy123           2                    7                    XYZ
abcxxyXYZxxy123           3                    13                   123
alfaxxybetaxxygama        1                    1                    alfa
alfaxxybetaxxygama        2                    8                    beta
alfaxxybetaxxygama        3                    15                   gama
```

Comment: I have to use this as a function that returns table containing only one column with separated items, as it is used later in my other procedures.
Probably your solution can be modified to be used in such a manner.